# Batch Script to find string in directory and all subdirectories

Tags: string, directory, root

I want to write a batch file which used the find command to find a string in the parent directory and all sub directories, and prints that output to a text file, then opens the text file when done. My code so far looks like this:

```
@echo off
set /p "var1= Enter the String to Find: "
for /F "delims=" %a in ('dir /B /S *.txt') do @(find /i "%var1" "%a" 1>nul 2>&1 && find /i "%var1" "%a") >> result.txt
start result.txt
```

But this is currently not even writing anything to result.txt, even though I am sure that where I am searching the string appears in multiple .txt files. I know it must be something syntax-wise but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few mistakes in your script:

1. There should not be a space after the equals sign of a `set` command. Specifically, remove the space after `set /p "var1=`.
2. To expand variables, you have to put a percent sign *before and after* the variable name, so instead of `%var` use `%var%`.
3. Not directly related to your problem, but why are you invoking `find` twice?

I've also made use of a temporary file, so that `result.txt` won't be searched by `find`.

Note that for if you're running the batch script from a *file*, You need to use double percent signs when you use loop variables, for example: `%%a`

Anyway, here's the fixed script, hopefully doing what you intended to do:

```
@echo off
set RESULT_FILE="result.txt"
set /p "var1=Enter the String to Find: "

pushd %~p0
type NUL > %RESULT_FILE%.tmp
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /S *.txt') do (
    for /f "tokens=3 delims=:" %%c in ('find /i /c "%var1%" "%%a"') do (
        for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('find /i "%var1%" "%%a"') do if %%c neq 0 echo %%f
    )
) >> "%RESULT_FILE%".tmp
move %RESULT_FILE%.tmp %RESULT_FILE% >nul 2>&1

:: Open the file
"%RESULT_FILE%"
popd
```

Comment: Is there any way I can get the script to search the directory and sub directories of where the script file actually is. Currently, if I run this as administrator it only finds files in the system32 folder, but I have the script in a folder on an external hard drive and want to search there.

Comment: I tired something like this 
set Pathname="U:\some_folder"
cd /d %Pathname%
but it seems to be getting stuck and nothing is written.

Comment: Actually, you insert the line `pushd %~p0` right after the first one, and the line `popd` at the very end of the script. It changes the current directory to `%~p0`, which expands to the directory where the script is located, and then changes back to the previous directory when the script is finished.

Comment: Ah I see the finds all work, but it still prints the path for every text file in the directories, even if that .txt does not contain the string. Is there a way I can make it only write to result.txt if the find is actually a success?

Comment: I'm sure there's a better solution that avoids the double invocation of `find`... anyway, I'm glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

just findstr abc *

in contrast, findstr /v will print all without abc